# org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.TransactionException: {"stack":"TXRejectedError: Exceeds block gas limit

Tags: solidity, ganache, web3j, solidity-0.8.x

I'm trying to communicate with my deployed contract using **web3j**. First I should let you know that I have 0 experience in web3j, I'm using it for the first time.

Goal: **I wanted to simply call that `addNewUser` method and return what it was returning to me.**

```
    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String addNewUser(@RequestParam String userAddress, @RequestParam String adminAddress) throws Exception {
        Web3jService service = new HttpService("http://localhost:7545");
        Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(service);

        String privatekey = "ac85e20fb3800f346a1082df9e0b3074adc6940346a9876e24649a5a89536774";
        BigInteger privkey = new BigInteger(privatekey, 16);
        ECKeyPair ecKeyPair = ECKeyPair.create(privkey);
        Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(ecKeyPair);
        NoOpProcessor processor = new NoOpProcessor(web3j);
        TransactionManager txManager = new FastRawTransactionManager(web3j, credentials, processor);
        ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider = new DefaultGasProvider();

        Contracts_SuperAdmin_sol_SuperAdmin contract = Contracts_SuperAdmin_sol_SuperAdmin.load("0xDdBf7640386f14b7b24A1A13f0EF0FF35901f32b", web3j, txManager, contractGasProvider);
//        return contract.addNewUser(userAddress,adminAddress).send().getTransactionHash();
        try{
            contract.addNewUser(userAddress,adminAddress).send();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("------");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("******");
        }
        return "";
    }
```

First of all, is the private key correct?

[image]

Then here goes the contract address:

[image]

But it gives the error saying: **`org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.TransactionException: {"stack":"TXRejectedError: Exceeds block gas limit\n`**